# delete Null vector in list of vectors

Tags: r

if i have a list of vectors and one of them is null how i can delete it ,for example i have this list :

```
[[1]]
{(2, 5), (3, 6), (4, 5), (5, 2), (5, 4), (5, 7), (6, 3), (6, 7), (7, 5), (7, 6)}

[[2]]
{(1, 4), (3, 4), (3, 6), (4, 1), (4, 3), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (5, 4), (6, 3),
 (6, 4), (6, 7), (7, 4), (7, 6), (8, 4)}

[[3]]
{(1, 8), (2, 5), (2, 8), (4, 5), (4, 8), (5, 2), (5, 4), (5, 7), (7, 5), (7, 8), (8, 1),
 (8, 2), (8, 4), (8, 7)}

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
{(1, 8), (3, 6), (6, 3), (6, 8), (8, 1), (8, 6)}

[[6]]
{(2, 5), (4, 5), (5, 2), (5, 4)}

[[7]]
NULL

[[8]]
NULL
```

so i want to delete the fourth the 7th and the 8th 
thanks

Comment: `x[lengths(x)>0]`?

Comment: @RichScriven Yeah, the question I list above actually has essentially the same answer you suggest.

Comment: @r2evans - that may give incorrect results on list elements like `character(0)`, since it's length 0 but not NULL

Comment: good point, I was looking for the exception, thanks (I'll leave it up to preserve the "not-best solution and why")

Comment: @RichScriven your function is working but the problem that i want to keep the index of the vectors and delete the Null ones

Comment: You mean you want the indexes to be 1,2,3,5,6?  Not possible.  R adjusts the iindexes internally.